# converting Parse.com object to string

Tags: javascript, html, css, parse-platform

What I have is when a user enters a name into a textbox and clicks a button, the value in the textbox is saved to the `Parse` database.

What iI'm trying to do is get the name that was added and add it to a div.

On this [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iwuvoq/2/edit), it's basically what I want, except it alerts `[object Object]` and not `thomas` in this case.

Comment: If you use `JSON.stringify(results)`, you'll see this in the `alert`: Successfully retrieved {"FirstName":"thomas","objectId":"CZrvYfY2DC","createdAt":"2013-04-29T15:46:22.610Z","updatedAt":"2013-04-29T15:46:22.610Z"} " - it's an object returned

Comment: thanks for your comment, unfortunately I want more control over the data than what JSON.stringify(results) provides (as far as i know at least) and results.attributes.FirstName method seem more fit for purpose. but still deserving of an up vote as it may be handy to those needing in the future.

Comment: My point wasn't for you to **use** `JSON.stringify` - it was just a way for you to see/understand you get an **object** back and you have to access it like `results.FirstName` to get the FirstName value.

Comment: ya that makes scene. its just when i saw how the result was printed to the screen i thought you meant that to just output all the data. sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem at all! I should've explained better in the first place :)

Comment: i noticed that i got "thomas" as the result is there anyway to get rid of the ""?

Comment: When you actually access it, like `results.FirstName`, the `""` shouldn't be there. It's just because of the representation of the object. Are you getting it when you specifically access the `FirstName`?

Comment: i tried divTag.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results.attributes.FirstName); and got "thomas" and tried divTag.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results.FirstName); and got undefined with no ""

Comment: Hmm that's interesting - I'm not sure why `results.FirstName` isn't working - I'm guessing it's a special object that you need to use `results.attributes.` first. Anyways, don't use `JSON.stringify` for printing things, especially basic types like string, number, boolean, etc. If you **need** to *print* an object/array, you can use `JSON.stringify`. Otherwise, just access the properties like `results.attributes.whatever` to retrieve them

Comment: Cool, thanks for the chat was bored at work anyway lol

Comment: Haha no problem. Let me know if you need more help with it, I'd be happy to try to explain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the specific part of the result you need. In your case, replace

```
query.first({
  success: function (results) {
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results + " ");
    divTag.innerHTML = results.toString();
  },
  error: function (error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

with

```
query.first({
  success: function (results) {
    alert("Successfully retrieved " +  results.attributes.FirstName + " ");
    divTag.innerHTML = results.attributes.FirstName.toString();
  },
  error: function (error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: that worked to get the name back thanks for that. The problem I face now is query.first is only taking the first object (as it should) but I need the last object (Newest added to the database). is there any way to query for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.get("FirstName") + " ");